EF Core modelBuilder OrderBy
I've got the following EF Core entities:
public class SchedulerJob
{
    public ICollection<ActionBase> Actions { get; init;}

    //...
}

public class ActionBase
{
    public int Index {get; init;}

    //...
}

On modelBuilder I currently have:
        modelBuilder.Entity<SchedulerJob>().Navigation(x => x.Actions).AutoInclude();
        modelBuilder.Entity<ActionBase>().UseTpcMappingStrategy();

However I'd like to always have Actions ordered by Index. For the life of me I can't find any documentation on how to do this...
I can't find anything that says whether it's supported or not to use .OrderBy() inside .Navigation() and can't see any other way of doing it either.
Any help would be appreciated.

What happens if you try .Navigation(x => x.Actions.OrderBy(....)).AutoInclude()

Not supported. Navigation must return a member access to a navigation property (sadly, this isn't documented). Maybe there are change requests for it already, otherwise you may consider submitting one.

@Charlieface pretty sure that's not supported but haven't tried it. Gert seems to be saying it's not supported at all so I just did it in my query... not quite what I wanted but guess it will have to do
